# How come the juniors in yowamushi pedal can only complete until their junior years? (Third year i think)

Tags: yowamushi-pedal

So repeatedly in yowamushi pedal, they kept saying that this is the juniors last chance to compete.

My assumption is they go to school for 6 years right. Last 2 years would be focused on the practical. So they have the first 4 years to focus on academics and other curricular activities.

The juniors kept saying that this is their last year but they still have a senior year right? Can they not compete if they are already in their senior year?

Comment: AFAIK, the setting of this anime is Japanese high school where the students have 3 years. Could you please clarify who the "juniors" are in the question?

Comment: the juniors were kinjou, tadokoro and makishima